# drawablePadding for RadioButton above API Level 16

Tags: android-layout, radio-button, android

I have a RadioButton and I am using a custom Image for button image. now I want to give space between image and the text. I have Used `android:drawablePadding` attribute to give space but it does not work above api level 16. There is one solution for api level above 16 is   `android:paddingLeft`. but this works for API level more than 16, for lower api levels it overlap the image and text. So please suggest a solution to provide space between RadioButton Image and text for all API levels.

Comment: Try to give some default space to your RadioButton Text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android:drawablePadding` works only for the compound drawables (drawableXYZ),
not for the `android:button` property.

Consider setting `android:button="@null"` and use
`android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_state_list"` or   `android:drawableRight="@drawable/your_state_list"`

An xml StateList is required to give your custom RadioButton a checked/unchecked state.

Comment: I didn't test that. Probably they fixed it to work the proper way. The suggested method should work under **ANY** API Level.

Comment: Yes You are right... Its working for every API Level. May be this was a bug and now they fixed it.